# Setting content of an element in tinymce textarea

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have a tinymce textarea (TinyMCE 3.5.11) that contains an element like

```
<span id="lastreplytimeee">...</span>
```

I need to access and change the content of this element using the span id as selector.

I have tried things like

```
tinyMCE.DOM.setHTML('lastreplytime', $input.val());
```

None worked.

Any suggestions?

this line is within .ready:

```
    $().ready(function() {   
    jQuery('.flexy_datepicker_input').datetimepicker({
    lang:'tr',
    format:'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    dayOfWeekStart:1,
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
    document.getElementById("lastreplytimeee").innerHTML = $input.val();
    }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Maybe try it,this code gets TinyMCE content and then replace some elements (TinyMCE 5)

```
tinymce.get('TinyMceID').setContent(
      tinymce.get('TinyMceID').getContent().replace(
        $(tinymce.get('TinyMceID').dom.doc.getElementById('lastreplytimeee')).get(0).outerHTML,
        `<span  id="lastreplytimeee">` + newValue + `</span>`)
        )
```

2.or use this

```
tinymce.get('TinyMceID').dom.setHTML("lastreplytimeee", "newValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("id")` gets the reference to that particular tag.
`.innerHTML` is to say assign value or display values in the HTML at that particular div you are referring to above.

Try to use-

```
document.getElementById("lastreplytimeee").innerHTML = $input.val();
```

If you are using jQuery, try this-

```
$("#lastreplytimeee").html = $input.val();
```

Hope it helps :) Happy Coding!

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work, I get TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

Comment: I see that you are using jQuery! Well, I have updated the answer for you.

Comment: $("#lastreplytimeee").html = $input.val(); doesn't do it either. I think somehow, tinymce hinders me from accessing elements inside the textarea via javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, tinymce requires its dom utility to access and play with an element inside it, like:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setHTML(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('selector'), 'some inner html');
```